# Non optional String automatically getting changed to optional

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I am facing a problem where the object which I have created is a non-optional value but somehow it is getting converted into an optional one.

I have tried in the playground also refer to the screenshot below. Does anyone know what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: `someProperty` _is_ optional. What are you talking about? `String!` is an implicitly unwrapped _optional_.

Comment: did you have any specific reason for making `someProperty` a `var` instead of initializing it as a `let` constant?

Comment: Don't post code as images, post it as text.

Comment: **Never ever** declare a property as implicit unwrapped optional which is initialized in an `init` method passing a non-optional value. Never. Remove the exclamation mark. If you really need an optional declare it as regular optional (`?`) and make the parameter optional, too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the implicitly unwrapped optional sign `!`. Do the class like this:

```
import UIKit

class SomeDataModelClass {
    var someProperty: String

    init(someProperty: String) {
        self.someProperty = someProperty
    }
}

let someObject = SomeDataModelClass(someProperty: "Non Optional String")
print(someObject.someProperty)
```

And you won't get the previous result.

Answer (score 0):

*Implicitly unwrapped optionals* (any type suffixed with a `!`) are optionals, underneath the surface. This recently changed in Swift 4+. Here is an excerpt from the Swift.org blog [*Reimplementation of Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals*](https://swift.org/blog/iuo/) (with emphasis added):

> *Implicitly unwrapped optionals* are optionals that are automatically unwrapped if needed for an expression to compile. To declare an optional that’s implicitly unwrapped, place a `!` after the type name rather than a `?`.
>
> A mental model many people have for implicitly unwrapped optionals is that they are a type, distinct from regular optionals. In Swift 3, that was *exactly* how they worked: declarations like `var a: Int?` would result in `a` having type `Optional<Int>`, and declarations like `var b: String!` would result in `b` having type `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>`.
>
> The *new* mental model for IUOs is one where you consider `!` to be a synonym for `?` with the addition that it adds a flag on the declaration letting the compiler know that the declared value can be implicitly unwrapped.

In your case, specifically, you are printing an implicitly unwrapped optional, which is really just a fancy optional, so it’s expected & correct behavior. If you want to print the string value itself, you’ll need to *explicitly* unwrap the value, `print(someObject.someProperty!)`. The linked blog post deep dives into the new reimplementation of IUOs & is worth a skim.

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly unwrapped optional is still optional. It just doesn’t look like that when you’re writing your code. So this property still can hold no value.

---

But for your specific need there is no reason to having implicitly unwrapped optional. Make it either non-optional or optional. Also you can use `struct` instead of class and then you can use default memberwise intializer

```
struct Model {
    var property: String
}

let object = Model(property: "text")
print(object.property)
```

> `text`